# How do recipe clippers/recipe scrapers/ recipe copier works on many web sites?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping

I am working in python-
I am asking this question out of curiosity and requirement. I have a requirement to create a recipe copier/**scraper** which can work on almost 20-25 website. All I know is scraping a website using beautifulsoup module of python 2.7 and it helps in scraping data when you know structure of a website.

But there are plenty of meal/recipe websites which provide recipe clipper/copier and they work so per

- [plan to eat](https://www.plantoeat.com/recipes)
- [One tsp](https://onetsp.com/clip/)
- [big oven](https://www.bigoven.com/clipper)
- [food network](http://recipes.foodnetwork.com/import-recipe)

and many more. They all provide an option to import recipe from other websites. Have they created a custom __scraper__which work on most of the websites or is there Any wonderfull API exist which they are using?

I have found one such custom **scraper**:
[Recipe scraper](https://github.com/hhursev/recipe-scraper)

but it is built in Python 3 and does not support python 2 so it is not much useful to me but when I went through the code I came to know it is using beautiful soup and wrote custom code to **scrape** content from all major recipe websites.

Can anyone help me to understand that howcome all the sites I listed and many more are creating recipe clippers??

Comment: They no doubt do it on a per site basis. If you think you are going to create some magic spider that will scrape what you want from any random site you are going to be disappointed

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham for clearing my doubt. So I have to write custom code for every website? That would be time taking work!

Comment: If you set it up correctly and use a framework like scrapy a lot of your codebase will be reusable but unless the template/logic for each site is identical you will have to treat each one individually.

Comment: FYI it's __scraper__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scrape__) not scrapper